# Cannot remove constness from type 'const char*'

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Our goal is to remove the const-ness from the type `const char*` so that the resulting type is `char *`.  Expected was that this can be done with `std::remove_const` or `std::remove_cv` or `std::decay`.

But this does not work. The documentation for the above operation says that *top-level* const-ness is removed, so it seems that in the described case the constness is *not* top-level.

The sample on page https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_const/ even documents in the line below that this is not possible:

```
    std::remove_const<const char*>::type b;    // const char* b
```

But why is that so?

The program below demonstrates the problem.  How can the type `ccs_t` be transformed to `cs_t` so that the second test passes?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <type_traits>
 
    int main() {
        using ccs_t = const char*;

        std::cout << "test1 " << (std::is_same<const char*, ccs_t>::value
            ? "passed" : "failed") << '\n';

        using cs_t = std::remove_cv<ccs_t>::type;

        std::cout << "test2 " << (std::is_same<char*, cs_t>::value
            ? "passed" : "failed") << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: `std::remove_const` removes top-level `const` only, i.e. it transforms `const char* const` into `const char*`. In your case you have to remove pointer, remove const and then add pointer.

Comment: The "topmost type" here refers to the pointer (`char *`) not the "lower type" (`char`). This is a *pointer* to a bunch of `const char`s.